# Get value of item from some elements before with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="do.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title_>Empire Burlesque</title_>
    <artist>Bobby</artist>
    <company>Columbia</company>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title_>Shirt2</title_>
    <artist>Bobby</artist>
    <company>Columbia2</company>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title_>Fingers</title_>
    <artist>Bobby</artist>
    <company>Columbia3</company>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title_>Zip1</title_>
    <artist>Bobby</artist>
    <company>---</company>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title_>Zip2</title_>
    <artist>Bobby</artist>
    <company>---</company>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

I need to replace  --- with previous meaningful data - Columbia3
I do next

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title_"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      <td>
          <xsl:variable name="NotStarted" select="preceding-sibling::cd[1]/company" />
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="company != '---'">
              <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$NotStarted" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As expected i got next html

```
Title   Artist
Empire Burlesque    Bobby   Columbia
Shirt2  Bobby   Columbia2
Fingers Bobby   Columbia3
Zip1    Bobby   Columbia3
Zip2    Bobby   ---
```

How i can iterate back to get last meaningful string to replace with or any other way? Thanks.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, i think its pretty clear here and no need for additional explanation. I also think what you are too-too-too rigorous here))

Comment: Not at all -- you could at least provide the exact wanted result -- if even this is missing, people can define "meaningful" as the literal string `"meaningful"` and give yo this: `<xsl:text>meaningful</xsl:text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be achieved by changing your **NotStarted** variable

```
<xsl:variable name="NotStarted" select="preceding-sibling::cd[1]/company" />
```

What this is currently doing is finding the immediately preceding sibling, regardless of content, and the getting its **company** element.  What you need to do is find the first preceding sibling which has a valid company name

```
<xsl:variable name="NotStarted" 
   select="preceding-sibling::cd[company != '---'][1]/company/text()"/>
```

It is worth noting, it is usually preferable to avoid the use of **xsl:for-each** and **xsl:choose** in XSLT, and try to utilitise the power of template matching. Here is an alternate XSLT which demonstrates this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Artist</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd"/>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="cd">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title_"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="company"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="company[text() = '---']">
      <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::cd[company != '---'][1]/company"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML sample, the following is output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Columbia</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Shirt2</td>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Columbia2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Fingers</td>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Columbia3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Zip1</td>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Columbia3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Zip2</td>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Columbia3</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pretty good answer, im new in xsl, and you were very helpful. Thanks